# Azure SDK v2.6. When publishing to azure I am constantly being told to download and install Azure SDK

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to deploy a LightSwitch application to Azure but every time I proceed and change my application server configuration I am told to download the Windows Azure SDK for .NET. I have installed and reinstalled way too many times now so I'm tearing my hair out. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

--Error Message
"The windows Azure SDK for .NET must be installed to enable publishing to Windows Azure. Lightswitch will load a web page to begin installation"

Answer (score 0):

Somebody at Microsoft claimed to have reproduced the same error (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/817291/the-windows-azure-sdk-for-net-must-be-installed) by clearing the publish settings as recommended by Dave Kidder (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david_kidder/archive/2012/12/05/declaring-lightswitch-publish-wizard-bankruptcy.aspx).

I've had issues switching between IIS and Azure as publishing targets which have been resolved by changes in that area but I found Dave Kidder's approach a little brutal. I blogged about a more targetted approach - http://www.finalcircuit.com/sequence-contains-more-than-one-matching-element-error-when-publishing. Good luck.